# When I go on Blender, the whole thing is pink

Tags: animation

I am creating this Minecraft animation and I saved and left my WIP, 2 hours later I came back on, went on my save and the whole world was pink, how do you fix it? Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=pink This should solve it. If not check this one: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Blender+pink+textures

Comment: The ones didn't work, I pressed on the "Find New Files" and when I tried to get my files back it said it could find them

Comment: It's hard to tell with a little information you've provided. Please add some images or even .blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then maybe we can help you. Did you painted textures in Texture Paint mode?

Comment: Pink means that the texture is missing. Is the file with the picture in the same place in the drive?

Comment: By default Images used on textures and backgrounds do not get saved as part of the .blend file, they are loaded from the disk on your computer. Blender has no way to know where you put your images or if you moved them to another folder. The same is true if you open a blend file created on a different computer. To make the file self contained, so that the images are saved as part of the .blend file, you have to pack them (file>External Data> pack all into .blend)